# Custom fields in tabs are not editable since upgrade to 4.7.1

Tags: custom-fields, 4.7

After upgrading to 4.7.1, when trying to edit custom fields in tabs, the edit popup opens and you can enter data (and it does client-side validation) but the data is not saved.

Moving the set of custom fields to `inline` rather than `tab` is a successful workaround.

I couldn't reproduce it on demo, but I could on my dev site which has no extensions in common so I think it is unlikely to be due to an extension. I noticed demo is running 4.7.2 ... is this issue known to be fixed in 4.7.2? If so I'll just wait for the release and work around in the meantime.

Comment: 4.7.2 was released just this morning! https://civicrm.org/blogs/kurund/announcing-civicrm-472-and-4613-release

Comment: @AllenHutchison great, thanks - I'll try it!

Answer (score 2):

This turned out to be a bug in said version and is now fixed.